# Replacing a div of text with individual spans as letters and iterating through it

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to replace a div of text with individual `span` elements of each letter, which is straightforward but I'm trying to have those spans font size increase incrementally and I can't figure out what to throw in the setTimeout function.

```
<div id ="foo"> Welcome to Here </div> 

function test() {

  let word = document.getElementById('foo');
  let arr = word.split("")
  word.innerHTML = "";
  arr.forEach((x,index) => {
    let newSpan = document.createElement('span')
    newSpan.innerHTML = x;
    word.appendChild(newSpan);
    setTimeout(() => {
    ????
       }, 100 + index*100)

 })    
}
```

Comment: The `getElementById()` function returns a reference to a DOM element, not to its text content.

Comment: Why do you need a setTimeout? can you not just do `word.innerText.split("")` to make it work?

Comment: @Pete I'm trying to increment the fontSize of each letter one at a time

Comment: why not just add a style attribute for that on the span? http://jsfiddle.net/eta78uj1/ - I incremented 2px at a time just so you can see it better

Comment: @Pete kinda just like that jsfiddle but I want the first letter to increment first then the 2nd one, etc.  That's why i wanted to use a timeout

Comment: Ok so just put the font thing inside the timeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do your split on the inner text of your element and the increase the font size of your span:

```js
function test() {

  const baseFontSize = 16;                       // starting font size
  const word = document.getElementById('foo');
  const text = word.innerText;                   // split this and not your element object
  const arr = text.split("");
  
  word.innerHTML = "";
  arr.forEach((x, index) => {
    let newSpan = document.createElement('span')
    newSpan.innerHTML = x;
    word.appendChild(newSpan);
    
    setTimeout(function() {
     newSpan.style.fontSize = (baseFontSize + (index * 2)) + 'px';  // increment by 2px
    }, 1000 * index)                                                 // increment each span a second after the last
  })
}

test();
```

```html
<div id="foo">Welcome to Here</div>
```

Comment: ah this is what I was looking for.  Makes sense now. thank you!

Comment: hey @pete .. would it make a different if I made the setTimeout right BEFORE appending it to the div?

Comment: damnt i did also have fix posted it to late :) but it still count to i hope

Answer (score 1):

he is another try with settimeout

```js
    function test() {
      var fontSize = 12;
      let word = document.getElementById('foo');
      let arr = word.innerHTML.split("")
      word.innerHTML = "";
      arr.forEach((x,index) => {
      var fs = (fontSize + index) +"px";
        let newSpan = document.createElement('span')
        newSpan.innerHTML = x;
        
        word.appendChild(newSpan);
        
        setTimeout(function(){ 
        
        newSpan.style.fontSize = fs
        }, 2000 + (index * 100));
     })    
    }

    test();
```

```css
    span{
    display : inline-block;
    font-size:12;

    }
```

```html
    <div id ="foo"> Welcome to Here </div>
```

Comment: thanks @alen.  I want to have the letters increase in size one at a time though, that's why I wanted to use a timeout to have the first letter change, followed by the 2nd, etc

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this code is that `getDocumentById()` will return a reference to the element, not the text itself.

If the inner content of your div is plain text, you can try this

```
var domElement = document.getElementById('foo');
var word = domElement.innerText; // Here you get the text itself
domElement.innerText = ''; // Here you clear the previous content which should be text
for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
  var spanElement = document.createElement('span');
  spanElement.innerText = word[i];
  domElement.appendChild(spanElement);
}
```

Now if you want to increase the size of the span, you can do it using the counter of the loop as you can see here

```
spanElement.style.fontSize = i
```

Comment: thanks but what if I wanted to increment fontSize sequentially.  I want the first span to increment, followed by the next, etc.  That's why I wanted to use a setTimeout